# Rewriting whole DOM via Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, templates, joomla, joomla-template

I have searched ALOT for this question and didnt find an answer,

I designed a complex HTML template and I tried to make a Joomla template based on it

I found the whole process time consuming and I cant get exactly same result as I wanted, also even If I do this I dont have a user friendly Joomla panel and for changing every module and component the Admin should know a basic HTML understanding to edit my tags and doesnt mess up my code

so I realized what If I use modern Joomla template instead with a user friendly panel

and bring the content to the page and rewrite the whole DOM via Javascript like this

```
1)first make variables and store the content on the rendered template
2)$('body').innerHTML = "" (make the DOM empty)
3)$('body').innerHTML => rerwrite my structure using variables I stored
```

then every element is exactly the same and my css, js files do the rest

Is it usual to do this way?
whats the problem with this method?

Thanks

Comment: My opinion is: **Don't**

Comment: This is messy and heavy, also non-user friendly. Also you'll lose event listeners on your page. If you need to change a few things on your page, try using Vue instead. Vue is pure awesomeness.

Comment: for SEO ? or this making the website loading slow?

Comment: Changing the WHOLE dom is never a good IDEA (IMO). If you're gonna do this and you don't want to rely on heavy code or a library, simply reload the page.

Comment: what other options do I have? improving the template I made from my HTML template ? or any other options?

Comment: `Google crawlers` doesn't recommend such things.